# Domino and sections: way to force DIVs and not As?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In Domino, the content of sections in documents are rendered wither as DIVs, with the content of the section already on the page, hidden or shown through CSS, or it is rendered as A tags, without the section's content, forcing a trip to the server when you open the section.

I am not sure what controls that behaviour, but it is different in IE8 and IE10.  This causes some issues as we have javascript code that opened up all the sections, asusming they were all DIVs, but they are now rendered as A tags.

Is there any way to force Domino to always render sections as DIVs?  A Notes.ini variable or some kind of configuration?  Already tried the UX-A tag and it only sets IE10 in IE8 compatibility mode, and it doesn't change Domino's way of serving the sections to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the Domino Designer 8.5 help file:

> Dynamic HTML sections
>   The Dynamic HTML (DHTML) used to render
>   collapsable sections for display with Microsoft Internet Explorer has
>   been enhanced and made available for use in other browsers which
>   support DHTML. The enhancement consists of using the  tag instead
>   of the  tag to delimit the sections, and using standard
>   JavaScript rather than IE-specific extensions for manipulating the
>   sections.  Use of this enhancement is configured in the
>   domino-data-directory\browser.cnf file. By default, the enhancement is
>   turned off, meaning that the original DHTML is generated. To enable
>   the enhancement, edit the browser.cnf file.

Possible values are (taken from the default config file on the server):

> Possible Values (case sensitive): None - client-side DHTML is not used
>   Legacy - client-side DHTML generated as originally implemented on
>   notes 6.0.  This was an
>            IE specific implementation. Standard - client-side DHTML using standards-based DHTML -- will work with IE 6 and 
>              Mozilla/5 based browsers.
>
> The property as shipped is configured to provide the same behavior as
>   originally implemented in notes 6.0.   Replace the rule with the ones
>   commented out to extend the use of DHTML sections to other browsers
>   and to avoid some IE 6 problems with the legacy implementation. Note
>   that some paragraph spacing in the Standard option may be different
>   from the other options and from the Notes client.

```
> Property DHTMLSections String None
> Rule    Legacy    MSIE [4-9]   
> Rule    Standard  MSIE [6-11]
> Rule    Standard  Mozilla/5
> Rule    Standard  Opera/7
```